# Java EE - [class <ClassName] uses a non-entity [class <ClassName>] as target entity in the relationship attribute

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, entity, persistence

I'm developing a Java EE application with persistence.

My *Car* class has a few *Reservation* and the *Reservation* class extends the *Quote* class.

For some reason *Reservation* is not an Entity class. My guess is that there is something wrong with the inheritance but I can't seem to figure it out.

*Car* looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=PERSIST, mappedBy="CarType")
    private CarType type;

    @OneToMany(cascade=REMOVE, mappedBy="Quote")
    private Set<Reservation> reservations;

    public Car() {}

    . 
    .
    .

    public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
        ...
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        ...
}
```

*Reservation* looks something like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Reservation")
public class Reservation extends Quote {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=AUTO)
    @Column(name="reservationId")
    private int reservationId;

    private int carId;

    public Reservation() {}

    public Reservation(Quote quote, int carId) {
        super(quote.getCarRenter(), quote.getStartDate(), quote.getEndDate(), 
            quote.getRentalCompany(), quote.getCarType(), quote.getRentalPrice());
        this.carId = carId;
    }

    .
    .
    .

    public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
        ...

    }

    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

*Quote* looks something like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Quote implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=AUTO)
    @Column(name="quoteId")
    private int quoteId;

    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Date startDate;
    @Temporal(DATE)
    private Date endDate;
    private String carRenter;
    private String rentalCompany;
    private String carType;
    private double rentalPrice;

    public Quote() {}

    public Quote(String carRenter, Date start, Date end, String rentalCompany, String carType, double rentalPrice) {
        ...
    }

    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        ...    
    }
}
```

Why is *Reservation* not a correct Entity class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing the following things:

- I removed the id from *Reservation* because it inherits it from *Quote*
- I manually added *Reservation* to *persistence.xml* as an Entity

Answer (score 1):

The entity Reservation must delete the @id because daughter inherits it from super class

Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate table defined for it.

Comment: Good answer. This in combination with manually adding Reservation to my Persistence.xml solved the problem.